# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory) - Working with servlets

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, servlets, filenotfoundexception

I'm working with hibernate and tomcat. What I did is create a form which has a file input. In the servlet I want to cast that file to a byte[]. But when I want to create de File, there's no directory: it only saves the image's name, not the path. Here is the error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: oldi.png (No such file or directory)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   control.servlets.AddGenericItem.doPost(AddGenericItem.java:46)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

The HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <font class="text_title">Image: </font>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="image" type="file">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$RegisterUserWizard$CreateUserStepContainer$CreateButton"
               id="ctl00_MainContent_RegisterUserWizard_CreateUserStepContainer_CreateButton"
               style="border-width:0px;">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Servlet:

```
public class AddGenericItem extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

//        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
        DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager();

        String name = httpServletRequest.getParameter("name");
        String description = httpServletRequest.getParameter("description");
        float price = Float.parseFloat(httpServletRequest.getParameter("price"));

        File image = new File(httpServletRequest.getParameter("image"));
        byte[] imageArray = new byte[(int) image.length()];
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(image);
            fileInputStream.read(imageArray);
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Admin admin = (Admin) httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        Brand brand = admin.getBrand();

        GenericItem genericItem = new GenericItem(name, description, imageArray, price,brand);

        GenericItemDAO genericItemDAO = databaseManager.getGenericItemDAO();

        genericItemDAO.beginTransaction();
        genericItemDAO.save(genericItem);

        try {
            genericItemDAO.commitTransaction();
        } catch (DatabaseAccessFailException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        } finally {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/adminPages/items.jsp");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

Comment: where is `oldi.png` present in the project?

Comment: are you trying to upload image?

Comment: oldi.png is not present in the project, I'm trying to upload it from the Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are working on File Upload.

The problem is at below line:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(image);
```

Servlet looks for the file at the server to read it but at that time it will not be there.

---

Use [Commons Fileupload library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) provided by Apache that makes it easy to add robust, high-performance, file upload capability to your servlets and web applications.

Find complete code [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/file-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp.html) and [here](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/articles/j2ee/fileupload.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187807/file-uploading-with-servlets)